# Adding a ' in a string SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble adding a field to a string. Right now I have a stored procedure running on a giant string (everything inside  '') but I am running into problems when creating the `Where` statement.

I have:

```
' Cast(Name AS varchar(max)) NOT IN (''Jimmy' + CHAR(39) + 's'')'
```

But I am getting an error with the `CHAR(39)`. How can I effectively make it look like `Jimmy's` inside the string? I know it's probably a stupid fix, but please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to double it up *again* since the apostrophe has to survive two rounds of delimiters. Try:

```
' Cast(Name AS varchar(max)) NOT IN (''Jimmy''''s'')'
```

For example, compare:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255) = N'SELECT ''Jimmy' + CHAR(39) + ''';';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Jimmy';'.
>   
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Incorrect syntax near 'Jimmy';'.

And this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255) = N'SELECT ''Jimmy''s'';';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ';'.

Finally:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255) = N'SELECT ''Jimmy''''s'';';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Result:

```
-------
Jimmy's
```

Comment: Yes I tried this but it picks it up as a " instead of a ' =\ I get the error: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ".

Comment: Oh wow never mind, I had an extra Char(39) at the end that was messing it up. Thanks!